# Mouse pointer too fast on Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

My problem is the mouse pointer speed is too high, and the GUI adjustments have no effect.  I found suggestions on using xinput to fix this.  Here's what I found:

```
nate@Cortana-Mint ~ $ xinput --list --short
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳   USB Keyboard                            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ gspca_zc3xx                               id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
nate@Cortana-Mint ~ $ xinput --list-props 12
Device 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE':
    Device Enabled (133):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (135): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (269): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (270): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (271):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (272):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (273):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (274):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (275):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (253): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (254):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (255):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (276): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (277): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (278):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (279):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (280):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (281): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (282): 274
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (283):    1
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (284):    0
    Device Node (256):  "/dev/input/event4"
    Device Product ID (257):    2362, 9505
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (285):   <no items>
    libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (258):    1
```

As you can see, I don't have the velocity scaling and deceleration properties, which is apparently what I'm supposed to set.  "Accel Speed" is already at 0, so not sure what I could do there.  I tried setting the acceleration via `xset` but that didn't seem to have any effect either.  I searched for info on updating mouse drivers in case that's the problem but didn't find much other than reinstalling xorg, which doesn't sound like what I want.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem as well.  You can try setting it with the *xinput* command.  Like:

```
xinput --set-prop 12 269 -0.5
```

Where the `12` is the mouse id, `269` is the code for "libinput Accel Speed", and the `-0.5` is telling it to go slower (I guess 0 is the baseline, so to slow it, you go below 0).  If that's still too fast, you can try -0.6, -0.7, etc.  To reset it, set it back to 0.0.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't been using Linux lately - also have gotten a new mouse.

Comment: Just as a note: The prop ID seems to vary between manufacturers. For my mouse, it is 291 instead of 269. Otherwise, the command worked perfectly.